# Reading files in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I keep trying to fead this  file into Fortran and output and format the data however I keep getting this message about The Runtime requesting to be terminated or something.

```
   Real X
   Real AVG, SUM, Y
   open(3, File = 'C: test.txt')
   open(5, File = 'C: test1.out')
   SUM = 0.
   Do 29, J = 1, 30
   Read(3, 60) X
60   Format(2x, F4.2)
   SUM = SUM + X
29   continue
   AVG = Sum / 30
   write(5, 65) AVG
65   Format(2x, 'Avg = ', F8.2)
*        Read *, Y
     Stop
     End
```

Comment: What OS is this? If this is Windows, shouldn't you have something like 'c:\test.txt' as a file path? When posting a question, it is best to include full and exact error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your OS (meaning, compiler and your actual operating system) there are few things that can go wrong with that example.

For a start

```
open(3, file='c:\test.txt')
```

is closer how that line is supposed to look like, although it is ususally best to just have the file in the same directory as the working program.

Comment: I agree, it's a bad idea for portability to use absolute path names like that.  Either use just a name to open a file in the current directory, or pass the full name from another source.